# Trouble with mysql, does not allow multiple foreign keys

Tags: mysql

I have three tables in my database

**Books(table)**

```
create table books (book_id int auto_increment, bookName varchar(10), qty int,primary key(book_id));
```

**Students(table)**

```
create table students (student_id int auto_increment,studentName varhchar(10),primary key(student_id));
```

**issuedBooks(table)**

```
create table issuedBooks(book_id int ,student_id int ,issued_date date, foreign key (book_id) references books(book_id), foreign key (students) references students(student_id));
```

mysql report an error that

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'references students(student_id))' at line 1
```

When I remove second foreign key, It works. I don't understand  what mistake did I do?

**Works(without any error, I just removed second foreign key)**

```
create table issuedBooks(book_id int ,student_id int,issued_date date, foreign key (book_id) references books(book_id));
```

Comment: Change `foreign key (students) references...` to `foreign key (student_id) references`

Comment: I did. But It did not work. create table issuedBooks(book_id int ,student_id int,issued_date date, foreign key (book_id) references books(book_id), foreign key student_id references students(student_id));

Comment: `foreign key (student_id) references` you missed the parentheses

Comment: It worked. Post it as an answer. I will accept it. Why are comment are getting highlighed. There is no option to highlight comment like in the questions?

Comment: It's fine, instead of the column name you had the table's name which is just a typo. You can highlight in the comments by enclosing it inside backticks.